# Application pushed to heroku but not working due to dotenv gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have pushed to heroku but the application will not run. I see that it is due to the dotenv gem. Is there a way around this? I need the dot-env gem in order to encrypt the basic auth user name and password. I'd prefer not to use devise or anything of that complexity as this is a simple application.

Below is my heroku terminal output, only issue is I dont really know how to spot errors/read the output.

```
  /app/config/application.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- dotenv (LoadError)
        from /app/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'





gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

gem 'pg'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem "font-awesome-rails"

gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]

gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  # gem 'dotenv-heroku'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configured the `dotenv` gem to be enabled only for the `development` and `test` environments:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
```

However, the application is started in `production` environment in Heroku. Therefore, the Rails application will crash because it tries to load the gem but it's not available.

You likely manually included the `dotenv` loading code somewhere in your application:

```
Dotenv::Railtie.load
```

You need to remove it (as dotenv will inject itself in the load process, when the gem is loaded), or wrap the code within a conditional block that executes it only if `Dotenv` is defined

```
if defined? Dotenv
  # ..
end
```

Unless you really need to manually load the library (and generally you don't), then simply remove the explicit statement, [explained in the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dotenv-rails/2.1.1).

> dotenv is initialized in your Rails app during the before_configuration callback, which is fired when the Application constant is defined in config/application.rb with class Application < Rails::Application. **If you need** it to be initialized sooner, you can manually call Dotenv::Railtie.load.

Comment: I do not know if I need them loaded immediately, I'm new-ish to rails. I just need them to use basic authentication. The only line I can find is in the application.rb file: 

 'require 'dotenv' ; Dotenv.load ".env.local", ".env.#{Rails.env}" ' When I remove that line, it will not let me run rake assets:precompile (that may be another issue) but if you could shed some light on that it would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

`dotenv` gem is used for load environment variables from .env into ENV in `development`.

and heroku used `production` environment. So, you need to just put this on `Gemfile`

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
```

Hope, this will helps you.

Comment: I have that in my gem file, but do I need to put it somewhere specifically in the gem file? I've added my gem file in the edits.

Answer (score 1):

dotenv is for managing your environment variables in your development environment. YOu need to manually create these variables on heroku.

Comment: I've done that. So not sure if there is something else wrong